# Pre- and post-action for ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I want to set busy flag and status bar text before command execution, and after it completes — reset flag and text. My working code is here:

```
Cmd = ReactiveCommand.Create();
Cmd.Subscribe(async _ => 
{
    IsBusy = true;
    StatusBarText = "Doing job...";
    try
    {
        var organization = await DoAsyncJob();
        //do smth w results
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        StatusBarText = "Ready";
});
```

Is it possible to do this in the "right way"?
Like this:

```
Cmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => DoAsyncJob());
//how to do pre-action?
//is exists more beautiful way to to post-action?
Cmd.Subscribe(res =>
{
    try
    {
        //do smth w results
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        StatusBarText = "Ready";
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
Cmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => DoAsyncJob());
//is exists more beautiful way to to post-action?
Cmd.Do(_ => 
{
    IsBusy = true;
    StatusBarText = "Doing job...";
})
.Subscribe(res =>
{
    try
    {
        //do smth w results
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        StatusBarText = "Ready";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, this is already built into ReactiveCommand:

```
Cmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => DoAsyncJob());
Cmd.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsBusy, out isBusy);
```

Also, never ever write this:

```
someObservable.Subscribe(async _ =>
```

`Subscribe` is *not* aware of async, its return value of the `onNext` is `void`. Instead, write this:

```
someObservable.SelectMany(async _ => {...}).Subscribe(x => {...});
```

You can put whatever you want in the Subscribe block, I usually write some sort of logging statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I understand, IsExecuting (and ThrownExceptions) works only with CreateAsyncTask. I have tried to use SelectMany, but when it calls, IsExecuting had already set to false.
I have read this article: [link](https://github.com/reactiveui/rxui-design-guidelines) and as I understand, more applicable way is (where CmdImpl - what I have in SelectMany):
`Cmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(CmdImpl);
Cmd.IsExecuting.Subscribe(b => IsBusy = b);`
Am I thinking in the right way?

Comment: IsExecuting only works if you use CreateAsyncXYZ, correct - if you use a SelectMany outside of the Observable, the command doesn't know about it. Instead of the Subscribe and the mutable value, I would really try to use ToProperty

Comment: If I need to set busy flag from several commands, should I do this the next way:
`this.WhenAnyObservable(vm => vm.Cmd1.IsExecuting, vm => vm.Cmd2.IsExecuting, ...).ToProperty(this, vm => vm.IsBusy, out isBusy);`
?